# Escape 2 Curly Braces / Angular JS braces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to print a string in my view that has curly braces like these:`{{ }}`, and it  doesn't come through. Is there a way I can escape/skip the curly braces parsing in Rails? The string I'm trying to print is like this:

```
@my_string = 'Hello {{name}}'
```

In my view, I'm printing the string like this:

```
<%= f.text_area raw(@my_string) %>  # Prints - "Hello"
```

I tried it without `raw`. It doesn't work either. I tried replacing the characters `{` and `}` with `&#123;` and `&#125;`, and I also tried replacing them with `\{` and `\}`. The string came through like this:

```
"Hello \{\{name\}\}"
```

I want the string to be:

```
Hello {{name}}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** This is an edit after the answer from Stefan. I didn't have to escape the characters in Rails. This issue was caused because of Angular JS. I'm using Angular JS and I had to provide ng-non-bindable class for it to not replace the `{{ }}`

Comment: `<%= raw(@my_string) %>` ?

Comment: @muistooshort - Yes, that was a typo. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The braces are replaced in the browser by a JavaScript framework like AngularJS. You have to tell the framework to not replace them.

In AngularJS you would use the [`ng-non-bindable`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angNonBindable) directive:

```
<%= f.text_area @my_string, class: "ng-non-bindable" %>
```

Comment: You just nailed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try for sumthing like this

```
<%= f.text_area "#{@my_string}" %>
```

see if it works

Answer (score -2):

this will bypass the angular

```
  {{  "{{ text }\}"   }}    # Prints - "{{ text }}"
```